# aria-hidden=true inside application

Tags: html, internet-explorer, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I’m having a chart-component in my web application which has `role="application"` to enable full keyboard-support. It contains elements which just are visual information (e.g. a legend) and shouldn’t be read by a screenreader since this could be confusing. All required information are stored in the elements and are read so the user can understand the content. Therefore I want to hide these elements.

```
<div class="chart" role="application" tabindex="0">
    <div class="legend" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true">
        Some text to explain the visual that 
        shouldn´t be read by any screenreader...
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <!-- content ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

But when the chart gets the focus the screenreader (NVDA 2014.4 or JAWS 16.0.1516 combined with IE11) reads **all** text inside the chart - independent of having `aria-hidden="true"` as well as `role="presentation"`. In Firefox it works as it should.

Any ideas about that?

Comment: Why are you using role="application" here? The content you are showing does not look like the sort of content that needs role="application".

Comment: Aside from my comment above, it looks like either an IE or a JAWS bug. You might want to use the inspector to see what is being exposed by the browser to determine whether it is IE or JAWS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: actually what is the use of aria-hidden ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in IE. Report this to Microsoft.